# Raw resource Uri causes FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, uri, filenotfoundexception

I need to get access to a file in the raw resource, I'm trying to get `Uri` which then later is used in FileInputStream, but I receive:

> 10-17 22:51:47.338: W/System.err(5619): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /raw/help_content (No such file or directory)

This is how I create `Uri`:

```
    Uri rawHelpZip = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/help_content");
```

I've tried with this as well:

```
    Uri rawHelpZip = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.help_content);
```

Note: the help_content is a zip file, does this have anything to do with my issues?

Comment: A raw resource is not a file on the device, so it cannot work with `FileInputStream`. Use `openRawResource()`, per ToYonos' answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare - then in what use case the Uri to android resource is used?

Comment: In theory, you could use it in an `Intent`. In practice, it is never used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this, it's cleaner to use the context built in method

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.help_content);
// Do something with the InputStrem
```

Comment: In other words, l have to save it in cache and then I can use it.

Comment: Just to make the answer complete,  could you please add when the Uri is used?

Comment: To add an example of when the raw resources Uri is used.

Comment: I don't know if the developer could ever knows the URI, I have only manipulated raw resource through InputStream.